# React: how to set state when there is more than one field to populate

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-select, formik

I'm trying to learn react.

I have a form which uses firestore data to populate arrays that are select fields in two form fields. Each uses a different firestore collection for its array.

Everything worked fine when I only had one array to use. I've added a second and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My form has:

```
state = {
        options: [],
        anzic: [],

    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        // const fsDB = firebase.firestore(); // Don't worry about this line if it comes from your config.
        let options = [];
        await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            options.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            options
        });
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        let anzic = [];
        await fsDB.collection("anzic_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            anzic.push({
                value: doc.data().Title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().Title + ' - ANZIC ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });
        this.setState({
            anzic
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = (formState, { resetForm }) => {
        const payload = {
            ...formState,
            fieldOfResearch: formState.fieldOfResearch.map(t => t.value),
            industrySector: formState.industrySector.map(t => t.value),
            createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            }
            console.log("formvalues", payload);

        fsDB
            .collection("funding_mandate")
            .add(payload)
            .then(docRef => {
            console.log("docRef>>>", docRef);
            resetForm(initialValues);
            })
            .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
            });
    };

    render() {
        const { options } = this.state.options; 
        const { anzic } = this.state.anzic;
```

Originally, the render method only had:

```
const { options } = this.state;
```

That worked fine. If i duplicate it for anzic, then the array of options for options is an empty list in the form when it renders.

I don't actually understand what these consts are  - so I'm struggling to learn from others who are using event handlers to update their forms. I think that approach probably isn't intended in this case because I use formik for forms.

Am I missing something in setting the arrays states?

Comment: Why do you have two different versions of `componentDidMount`?

Comment: this `const { options } = this.state;` was okay. Take a look at how to destructure https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Also, dont mutate state directly? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state

also as philip mentioned, why 2 `componentDidMount` methods?

Comment: thanks. i put it back that way for both arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `componentDidMount` remove the other one and use one.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  // const fsDB = firebase.firestore(); // Don't worry about this line if it comes from your config.
  let options = [];
  let anzic = [];

  await fsDB
    .collection('abs_for_codes')
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        options.push({
          value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
          label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
        });
      });
    });

  await fsDB
    .collection('anzic_codes')
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        anzic.push({
          value: doc.data().Title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
          label: doc.data().Title + ' - ANZIC ' + doc.id
        });
      });
    });
  this.setState({
    options,
    anzic
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but then both of the arrays populate (I can see them loading in the console) and both form fields say they have no options)

Comment: what happens when yo console log this values?

Comment: actually  -this works if I put the consts back as: render() {
        const { options } = this.state; 
        const { anzic } = this.state;

Comment: you can also do `const { options, anzic } = this.state;` in one line.